# Real time face detection using Viola and Jones in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, viola-jones

I am looking to detect faces in real time video captured from laptop camera. I use MATLAB R2011a (not the latest one) which does not have any Cascade Object Classifier function to identify face detection.

I have used a package http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29437-viola-jones-object-detection

This code is able to identify modestly on images but when I do the same on video's (taking each frame and identify face in it) its taking lots of time and thus not able to stream video.

So,

1. How should I able to detect faces real time using MATLAB R2011a
2. Is viola & jones algorithm suitable for it?
3. Are there any external implementations that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

A more recent and updated approach than Viola and Jones's detector is [SURF cascade](https://sites.google.com/site/leeplus/publications/facedetectionusingsurfcascade). It should run faster with better results.
I also think there is an implementation of this method for windows platforms [here](https://sites.google.com/site/leeplus/publications/learningsurfcascadeforfastandaccurateobjectdetection).

Comment: @lamcool you'll have to get your hands a little dirty if you want something real-time that actually works...

Answer (score 0):

First you  have to install matlab version R2012b or onward because VIOLA JONES algo is released in 2012 and prvious versions before R2012a cant run this Algorithem .... so u should first change the version and then the real time detection code is on every site.....